# How to update respected field value with specific related values

Tags: mysql, join

We have two tables viz. `products` and `orders`,
actually we had done mistake, and forgot to insert `product_id` in `orders` table and insterted `product_sku`, now we have tried

```
UPDATE `crm_order_products` SET product_id = 
(SELECT p.product_id FROM crm_products p 
 LEFT JOIN crm_order_products o 
ON p.product_sku = o.product_sku)
```

Comment: Can you show us the table definitions and some sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The present usage of your JOIN is not correct to update the value since you might get more than 1 row from the result of your `select` query which will result in an error. You need to use the proper JOIN to update the value in your table.Try this:

```
UPDATE crm_order_products o 
    JOIN crm_products p ON p.product_sku = o.product_sku 
SET o.product_id = p.product_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing an `UPDATE` combined with an `INNER JOIN`:

```
UPDATE crm_order_products a
INNER JOIN crm_products b
    ON a.product_sku = b.product_sku
SET a.product_id = b.product_id
```